# MySQL update field from latest field in another table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I keep running into issue trying to implement the solutions I'm finding for what I thought would be a simple query.

**SETUP:**

Table 1:    UID, Field1, TimeStamp

Table 2: UID, fk_table1UID, Field1, TimeStamp

Table 1 has an on before update trigger, that inserts the entire OLD row into Table 2.  (Effectively keeping a change log of table 1)

Table 2 also has a Foriegn key constraint to of fk_table1UID to table1.UID

**PROBLEM:**

All I'm trying to do is build a query that will

(pseudo code)
update table1.Field1 WHERE UID = X(user input) 
with 
table2.Field1 WHERE table2.TimeStamp = max(table2.TimeStamp) AND table2.fk_table2UID = table1.UID

I have tried different attempts at Update with inner joins, but I run into an issue saying I can't reference a table that has been invoked or something.  (I believe has to do with my trigger..)

**QUESTION:**

How can I pull this off in a single call query?

Comment: hi DarbyM, its fine with me if your marked Barmar's answer but let me know if my answer works or not. for learning purposes. thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
UPDATE table1
       SET table1.Field1 = (SELECT table2.Field1 FROM table2 WHERE table2.UIDfk = X ORDER BY table2.TimeStamp DESC LIMIT 1)
WHERE table1.UID = X
```

Comment: Are you sure that will work? MySQL has restrictions on when you can use `LIMIT` in a subquery, and I think this might be one of them.

Comment: not sure really, i'm not a mySQL expert but this kind of query will work on ORACLE and SQL Server using ROWNUM and TOP respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Join with a subquery that returns the desired value.

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1
JOIN (SELECT Field1 FROM table2
      WHERE fk_table1UID = @X
      ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC
      LIMIT 1) AS t2
SET t1.Field1 = t2.Field1
WHERE UID = @X
```

Comment: I'm going to try this again when I get to the computer later today. But I believe there is an issue with doing it this way when table one also has a trigger that updates table 2.

Comment: It seems to me like this whole operation may have to be done in a transaction. So I can lock a row in table 2 and table one at the same time and set the result from table 2 to a variable use that variable in the table 1 update. The problem is I have not worked with start transaction so I'm not familiar how to do that.

Comment: Each query is automatically done in its own transaction. You only need a transaction if you split it up into separate queries.